# Pass parameter data from JQuery/Ajax call to Jersey web service

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jersey

```
            $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8080/TestApp/resources/Test",
                type:"GET",
                data:userName :"userName",
                cache: false,
                success:function(result){   
                    alert(result);
                },
            });
```

Above is the JQuery code I'm using to call the service. How can I get the `userName` parameter to the

```
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {

        return "Hello ";
    }
```

Similar to a `request.getParameter("")` in servlet. In my understating `@QueryParam`, `@PathParam`, `@FormParam` are used for different purposes or can they be used to to get the parameter. (I have tried all three and failed). Kindly correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

> The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to
>   the HTTP container com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:
>   Exception obtaining parameters    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:165)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)

Did the changes and getting an exception as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data attribute has to be a plain js object, String or an array (See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So, in your code, the data element ought to be

```
data:{userName:'UserName'}
```

Comment: @QueryParam gave the correct value, and after your change It works fine. Thanks a lot :)